# Updating multiple line in a console application

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, console-application

I've been struggling with `Parallel.For` and local variable. I'm trying to update percentages in a console app from a parallel for. I add page in multiple document and I would like an update on the percentage for each document.

Here's my attempt so far :

I'm taking the number of the line with `Console.CursorTop`, and I want to pass it to a method who's gonna override the line.

Loop from Program.cs

```
Parallel.For(0, generationFile.nbOfFile, optionsParallel,
    i =>
    {                    
        string fileName = $"{tmpDirectoryPath}/{i + 1}_{guid}.pdf";
        AddPage(fileName, generationFile, i);
    });
```

The `AddPage` method

```
private static void AddPage(string fileName, GenerationFile generationFile, int i)
{
    var cursorPosition = Console.CursorTop;

    //Ajout des pages
    for (int j = 0; j < generationFile.SizeMaxFile; j++)
    {
        Page page = Page.Create(outDoc, size);
        AddText(outDoc, page, font, 14, i, fileName, j, generationFile.SizeMaxFile);
        for (int k = 0; k < 292; k++)
        {
            AddImage(outDoc, page, 30, 30);
        }
        outDoc.Pages.Add(page);
        ConsoleManager.UpdateConsole(i, j, cursorPosition, generationFile);
    }
}
```

The `UpdateConsole` method

```
public static void UpdateConsole(int fileNumber, double progression, int cursorPosition, GenerationFile generationFile)
{
    progression = (progression / 100) * generationFile.ArchiveESC; 
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, cursorPosition);
    Console.WriteLine($"\rFichier n°{fileNumber + 1}/{generationFile.SizeMaxFile} en cours de création : {progression}%       ", Console.ForegroundColor);
}
```

I think everything works fine, except for the `cursorPosition` who take one value at the beginning and never change, so the same line is updated. I understand that there is something to do with local and/or shared variable, but I'm fairly new in parallel processing so even with the other threads on this topic and the MSDN, I don't understand what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I prefer to handle progress reporting is to have all worker threads report to a shared progress field, and have a separate timer that reads this fields and reports the progress to the user. This lets me control how often progress is reported, regardless of how fast items are processed. I also want an abstraction layer that allows different ways to report progress. After all, the same method might be used from console, the UI, or not at all.

For example something like this:

```
public interface IMyProgress
{
    void Increment(int incrementValue);
}

public sealed class MyProgress : IMyProgress, IDisposable
{
    private readonly int totalItems;
    private readonly Timer myTimer;
    private volatile int progress;
    private int lastUpdatedProgress;
    public MyProgress(TimeSpan progressFrequency, int totalItems)
    {
        this.totalItems = totalItems;
        myTimer = new Timer(progressFrequency.TotalMilliseconds);
        myTimer.Elapsed += OnElapsed;
        myTimer.Start();
    }

    private void OnElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        var currentProgress = progress;
        if (lastUpdatedProgress != currentProgress)
        {
            lastUpdatedProgress = currentProgress;
            var percent = currentProgress * 100 / (double)totalItems;
            Console.Write($"\rWork progress: {percent}%");
        }
    }
    public void Increment(int incrementValue) => Interlocked.Add(ref progress, incrementValue);
    public void Dispose() => myTimer?.Dispose();
}
```

This can be called from a parallel method like:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

    var myWorkItems = Enumerable.Range(1, 10000).ToList();
    using var progress = new MyProgress(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), myWorkItems.Count);
    DoProcessing(myWorkItems, progress);
}

private static void DoProcessing(IEnumerable<int> items, IMyProgress progress)
{
    Parallel.ForEach(items, item =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(20);
        progress.Increment(1);
    });
}
```

I would be a bit careful when using carriage returns. In my experience console applications tend to be used by other programs as much as by humans, and then it is likely that the output will be redirected to a file, and that does not support carriage returns. So I would try to make the output look good.

I would avoid trying to move the cursor around. I have tried that, but the result was unsatisfactory, YMMV.

Comment: That's not exactly what I wanted, but it's enough. Thank you very much, for the advice too :)